# Use result of query in a function (postgres 8.3)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do something like this:

```
select char_length(select text_field from table where key = 1)
```

This won't work, and I presume, because the return type of a query is a table, not a string or text variable.

Is there a way to specify row,col of the result from a select statement?

edit: I overlooked to mention, that char_length is a function.

Comment: Why do you do it that complicated? Why not simply pass `text_field` to the function? Is there a reason why you do it that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When passing the result of a query to a function, simply wrap the query in brackets:

```
select char_length((select text_field from table where key = 1));
```

The outer set of brackets is for the function, the inner set converts a query to a result.

This syntax is not specific to postgres - it applies to all SQL servers.

[This link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/81b7e/1) shows the above code executing correctly (thanks to [@Fahim Parkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066828/fahim-parkar) for this)

Although, you could re-factor your query to not require this syntax, nevertheless this is how you "pass the result of a query to a function".

Comment: @FahimParkar Thanks for the test case - I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 2):

```
select char_length(text_field) from "table" where key = 1
```

Comment: will this query work?? table is a reserved keyword. EVEN this syntax is INVALID :D :)

Comment: @FahimParkar: good point I actually only did copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
select char_length(text_field) from "table" where key = 1
```

Also I believe, your table name is not `table`.

Comment: char_length is a function. I am trying to find the length of the text_field. For sanity's sake, I did try your fix, and it did not work.

Comment: The syntax is invalid for Postgres because it uses the standard double quotes not those non-standard dreaded backticks. It should be `"table"` instead

Answer (score 0):

Assuming key is a primary key or unique key the first example below will work. It works only if the sub-query returns only 1 row. The second example will work for 1 or more rows.

```
select char_length((select text_field from table where key = 1));
select char_length(text_field) from table where key = 1;
```